# Mongoose - FindOne() inside Multer

Tags: express, mongoose, multipartform-data, multer

I am sending formData to my express app like so:

```
itemFactory.saveItem = function(item, callback){

    var formData = new FormData();

    for(var i = 0; i < item.photos.length; i++){
        formData.append('photos', item.photos[i]);
    }       
    for(var key in item){
        formData.append(key, item[key])     
    }

    return $http.post('/api/item/', formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).success(callback);

};
```

I am saving a new item to my mongoose DB.  Now everything is working perfectly.  But I want to detect duplicates using mongoose `findOne()`, and not just let mongoose handle detecting if a duplicate key exists when writing to the DB.  Because my images get uploaded regardless at this stage, if a duplicate key exists or not.  Because it only detects the duplicate on `save()`

The problem now, in my express app, is when I am using `findOne()`, Multer() has not yet decoded my formData. ex:

```
router.post('/item', function(req, res){
    Vehicle.findOne({ id: String(req.body.id) }, function(error, item){

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({...})
        var upload = multer({
                         storage: storage
                     }).any();

        upload(req, res, function(error){
            //formData is only available here via req.body
            //and not at findOne() stage.
        });

    });
});
```

I cannot do the findOne inside the upload because then the files would be uploaded anyway and then only detect a duplicate.

I tried another `multer().any()` function for getting the formData just after the `.post()` but that did not seem to work.  I don't think I can do this:

```
var detectItem = multer().any()
detectItem(req, res, function(){

    Vehicle.findOne({ id: String(req.body.id) }, function(error, item){

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({...})
        var upload = multer({
                         storage: storage
                     }).any();

        upload(req, res, function(error){
            //formData is only available here via req.body
            //and not at findOne() stage.
        });

})
```

It does not seem to like me using a multer function inside a multer function.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to use [file filter](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) and check for duplicates there?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet.  I am quickly going to take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: @rkm, I need to find duplicates in the DB, file filter only checks for duplicate fields in the current data.

Comment: If you have access to request data inside `fileFilter` you can check in the DB and based on the response reject duplicates.

Comment: @rkm I played with fileFilter and it solved my issue.  If you post an answer, I  will accept.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fileFilter](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) option to control which files are accepted.

It could be something like this:

```
function filFilter (req, file, cb) {
    Vehicle
        .findOne({ id: req.body.id })
        .then(item => {
            cb(null, !item); // Skip if item exists (passing false skips file)
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  fileFilter did the trick for me.  The only issue I struggled with was when using fileFilter, was making sure that I passed the fields before passing the files when appending my formData.  After that, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could separate them into two middlewares

```
app.post('/item', function(req, res, next){

    //this middleware is used to check duplicate

    Vehicle.findOne({id:req.body.id}).then(function(item){
        if(item) res.end() //if item existed, send response directly
        else next() //if item not existed, continue to next middleware  
    })

}, function(req, res){

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({...})
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();

    upload(req, res, function(error){
        // ...
    });

})
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, this actually looks great.  Will implement and let you know.

Comment: The problem is that I still only have scope of req.body.whatever inside my upload() function.  So Vehicle.findOne() is always going to return undefined.